# using the sitemap package with django on heroku

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pymongo, sitemap

Installing sitemap on heroku and getting it run is showing the following issue below. I'm following the advice of:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/
```

and putting sitemaps into my requirements.txt

However when executing www.xyz.com/sitemaps.xml, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /sitemap.xml
'function' object has no attribute 'itervalues'


Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.xyx.com/sitemap.xml
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'function' object has no attribute 'itervalues'
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py in itervalues, line 494
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

So here is what I have in stettings:

INSTALLED_APPS: `'django.contrib.sitemaps'`

and in requirements.txt:

`sitemap`

and in urls.py:

```
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemap}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
```

Where does the issue arise?

In terms of the way I want to use sitemaps:

One of the issues looking at some of these examples is that I have no models defined. Everything is running off the MongoDB. Additionally pages are accessed from: , so is there a way that I can use sitemaps bearing in mind I have very very few views - but thousands of pages. How can I best automatically build the sitemap without expressly having models.

I suspect the confusion arises that there are no models defined, so that I will need to generate a list of URL's that correspond to the views that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put it in requirements.txt, it's part of Django so is already installed.

The error is because you have only done half of the configuration; you need to define a [Sitemap class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-classes) and refer to that inside the dictionary in your URL pattern

Comment: What about GenericSiteMap if I don't want anything specific, is this built in, ready to go? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/sitemaps/#Sitemap

Comment: Absolutely, just see [the example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#example).

Comment: I don't have models expressly set-up, but have plenty of views. What is the Entry functionality all about. Is there a minimal way of achieving this.

Comment: One of the issues looking at some of these examples is that I have no models defined. Everything is running off the MongoDB. Additionally pages are accessed from: <a href="/xxxx/?option={{ com.xyz }}">, so is there a way that I can use sitemaps?

Comment: Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. Your sitemap class just needs to provide a list of items, which can come from anywhere, and methods to return their location and last modified time. (Although I would seriously question why your URLs are in that form: you should be passing the values as part of the path itself, and this has nothing to do with MongoDB.)

Comment: I was thinking perhaps there was more under the hood here in terms of a way to include all the views more automatically. I can generate the urls, from a method along with the date modified.